# Find pattern and replace

Tags: r

A similar question was probably asked but here goes :

Suppose I have the following erronous dates in my df (in numeric format such that yyyymmdd): 20169904, 20179999, 20161099. These dates are from my date column, where many dates are wrong - no such thing as day = 99 or month = 99.

Now I wish to ONLY change the 99 in dd to 01. In other words, I need to find ONLY the dates that are yyyymm99 and change them to yyyymm01. I am not having trouble with str_sub(df$date,7,8) <- 01. However, this changes all dd in the column to 01. I only need to change those that are yyyymm99.

Using pipes or multi-step solutions are both ok with me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share a little more sample data in valid R syntax, include a few cases that shouldn't be modified as well as a few that should, along with the desired result for the sample input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `gsub()`:

```
gsub("99$", "01", df$date)
```

The `$` in regular expressions means "end of line" or "end of string". With `"99$"`, `gsub()` only matches "99" at the end of the string.

Comment: Notice the first example OP gives, `"20169904"` -- this won't work for that. But presumably `"19990504"` should be kept as-is.

Comment: OP repeatedly specifies: "I need to find ONLY the dates that are yyyymm99 and change them to yyyymm01."

Comment: Thank you a lot  @kitu. Your solution worked perfectly ! I complicated the solution with stringr for no reason. Do you mind explaining how to interpret the $ in 99 ? would the solution differ if you did ''$99'' instead ? Just for enlightenment.

Comment: @GabraNohmie I updated my answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R solution that will replace 99s in the `mm` part of the string if you need that as well, and will work if there are 99s in both the `mm` and `dd` portions.

```
df <- data.frame(date = c("19990104", "20160399", "19901003", "20199904", "20169999"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$new_date <- sapply(df$date, function(x) {

  if(!is.na(as.Date(x, format = "%Y%m%d"))) {

    return(x) 

  }

  new_date <- x

  if(grepl(".99$", x)) {

    new_date <- paste0(substr(x, 1, 6), "01")

  }

  if(grepl("^\\d{4}99\\d{2}", new_date)) {

    new_date <- paste0(substr(new_date, 1, 4), "01", substr(new_date, 7, 8))

  }

  return(new_date)

})
```

And here's the result.

```
      date new_date
1 19990104 19990104
2 20160399 20160301
3 19901003 19901003
4 20199904 20190104
5 20169999 20160101
```